# Modify d3.js Hive Plot to have 3 vertical axes and only A-B or B-C linkages

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I am beginning to work with the [D3.js Hive Plot example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2066415).

I would like to modify this hive plot so that the three axes are vertical (a, b, c) and connections can be made between axis a and axis b or between axis b and axis c. But not between axis a and c.

Do you think this hive plot code is what I should use to do this, or should I write something else on my own? I'm just beginning with D3 so I would prefer to make small changes to existing the hive plot code to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the connection between depends on the connection that you use. In the example there are many edges that connect the three axes:

```
var links = [
  {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[2]},
  {source: nodes[1], target: nodes[3]},
  {source: nodes[2], target: nodes[4]},
  {source: nodes[2], target: nodes[5]},
  {source: nodes[3], target: nodes[5]},
  {source: nodes[4], target: nodes[0]},
  {source: nodes[5], target: nodes[1]}
]
```